# React native error in socketcluster-client error

Tags: android, npm, react-native

I get this error when I run on android emulatorwith `npm run android` command.

and cmd error :

10:54:45 AM: Warning: 'react-native-vector-icons' peer depencency missing. Run `npm ls` in C:\Users\Sukeshu\Desktop\abc\SocialApp to see full warning.

If there is an issue running your project, please run `npm install` in C:\Users\Sukeshu\Desktop\abc\SocialApp and restart.

10:55:27 AM: (node:7632) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2865): UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module `C:\Users\Sukeshu\Desktop\abc\SocialApp\node_modules\socketcluster-client\lib\sctransport.j\lib\ws-browser.js` from `C:\Users\Sukeshu\Desktop\abc\SocialApp\node_modules\socketcluster-client\lib\sctransport.js`: Directory C:\Users\Sukeshu\Desktop\abc\SocialApp\node_modules\socketcluster-client\lib\sctransport.j\lib\ws-browser.js doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

You can Enter following commands :

1. npm i react-native-vector-icons --save
2. react-native link
3. cd android && gradlew clean
4. cd .. && react-native run-android

Comment: OK :) @SukeshThakare